# Scheduled task on .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, scheduled-tasks, quartz.net

I need to convert a couple of scheduled tasks from the Scheduler task of widows server to a standalone application using .Net.

In the past I've used Quartz on .Net framework 4.x, having some small issue with multiple long running tasks based on different schedulers.

Now I'm using .Net 5 and I'm wondering if there is a new way to schedule tasks, like the worker service or it's still better and more flexible to use Quartz.Net.

Since I need to run long time tasks, from 30s to 2 hrs, I need to create a timed background task, using System.Threading.Timer

The code should be the following:

```
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service running.");

        _timer = new Timer(DoSomething, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 
            TimeSpan.FromHours(24));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

and it should call DoSomething every 24 hrs.

My doubts are:

- When does it start to work and to count the 24hrs, when I first run
  the application?
- How can I say that the task must be run at a
  specific time in a day, at midnight for example?
- Is the Worker Service suitable for managing scheduled tasks?

Comment: HangFire, Quartz.Net, Coravel. All come with not just timers but queues with retries, priorities, chaining, dashboards. There's far more to scheduling tasks than just a timer. How are you going to check that your jobs run? What about errors? What if you want to run a job on demand? Windows' Task Scheduler offers a lot of functionality you've come to depend on without noticing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're right, I completely agree.

Comment: A worker service is nothing more than a console application with a BackgroundService, something you could create yourself by adding a hosted service to a Generic Host. It doesn't offer *any* scheduling functionality itself. You can use that BackgroundService to host a scheduling library like HangFire, Coravel or Quartz.NET. If you base the worker service on the Web SDK (or create a basic ASP.NET Core project and add a BackgroundService) you can host the web dashboard of your favorite scheduling library on the same application

Comment: [Hangfire's Getting Started](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-core-applications.html) tutorial for ASP.NET Core shows how to add the library, dashboard and use a database as a backing store for jobs. Hangfire has its own BackgroundService that runs the jobs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hangfire seems to be more advanced than Quartz.Net, isn't it?

Comment: Just adding a comment if you end up with using Quartz.NET, there's couple quite useful integration packages available, for this case the hosted service + DI integration https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/hosted-services-integration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When does it start to work and to count the 24hrs, when I first run the application?

Yes. Set a breakpoint and start your application. You'll see how quickly it fires.

> Is the Worker Service suitable for managing scheduled tasks?

Yes.

> How can I say that the task must be run at a specific time in a day, at midnight for example?

Let's take a look at this code:

```cs
public sealed class MyTimedBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{

    private static int SecondsUntilMidnight()
    {
        return (int)(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1.0) - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var countdown = SecondsUntilMidnight();

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (countdown-- <= 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    await OnTimerFiredAsync(stoppingToken);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    // TODO: log exception
                }
                finally
                {
                    countdown = SecondsUntilMidnight();
                }
            }
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    private async Task OnTimerFiredAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        // do your work here
        Debug.WriteLine("Simulating heavy I/O bound work");
        await Task.Delay(2000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

This doesn't use `System.Threading.Timer` at all incase you are worried about the timer never actually firing off because of some boundary. Some people are paranoid of this. I have *never* had that happen to me. And I use `Timer` a lot for this type of work.

It will calculates the number of seconds until midnight then loop until it gets there.

This is a non-reentrant timer and there will be slight time slippage due to the business logic for processing the delay.

Here is another example using `System.Threading.Timer`:

```cs
public sealed class MyTimedBackgroundService : IHostedService
{
    private Timer _t;

    private static int MilliSecondsUntilMidnight()
    {
        return (int)(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1.0) - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // set up a timer to be non-reentrant
        _t = new Timer(async _ => await OnTimerFiredAsync(cancellationToken),
            null, MilliSecondsUntilMidnight(), Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _t?.Dispose();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task OnTimerFiredAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            // do your work here
            Debug.WriteLine("Simulating heavy I/O bound work");
            await Task.Delay(2000, cancellationToken);
        }
        finally
        {
            // set timer to fire off again
            _t?.Change(MilliSecondsUntilMidnight(), Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }
}
```

*(this code was not tested, there may be some spelling/syntax errors)*

This is a non-reentrant timer meaning you are guaranteed that it will not fire off again if it's currently processing data.

It will calculates the number of milliseconds until midnight then set a timer based on that calculation.

This idea was taken [from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks).

Both of these examples can be injected as so:

```
services.AddHostedService<MyTimedBackgroundService>();
```

*Cloud Native Warning:*

Keep in mind that since these examples are local to your application, that if your application scales up horizontally where you have more than one instance running, you will be running *two or more* timers, just in separate processes. Just a friendly reminder. If your application will never scale, then ignore this warning.

Comment: there is a solution for horizontal scale? Im thinking about control the execution of all containers using an parameter on a redis cache database to enable 1 execution a time for this background service

Comment: @ArthurMelo -- I would move the timer to an external service such as an Azure Function and set it on a CRON job which would fire off and hit an endpoint on your service.

Comment: Can I start/stop a scheduled task from asp.net core MVC?

Comment: @Cenk -- You could, yes. But you'd have to implement the details yourself. You could make a property `static` and share it between a Transient and Hosted version of the same service.