# .NET Core IHostedService throws "A task was canceled" immediately

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I'm trying to build a service into my .NET Core 3.1 application that runs hourly. My service runs each hour (i.e. hits a breakpoint in `StartAsync()`), but the implementation throws the following error immediately:

> A task was canceled

I've searched quite a bit, however I'm having difficulty finding helpful responses; it seems these are most commonly thrown when using `HttpClient`, which is not relevant to my case.

That said, I have a hunch that I should be awaiting *something*, but my attempts to add `await` resulted in the application hanging on startup (I imagine I was unintentionally awaiting the full hourly iteration...?). The [tutorial I've been following](https://stacksecrets.com/dot-net-core/scheduled-repeating-task-with-net-core) does not use `await` anywhere; barring an oversight (very possible), my code seems identical to the example shown.

I've pulled out the guts of `ExecuteAll()` to confirm the code within works.

Thanks.

```cs
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
  var nextRunTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(DateTime.UtcNow.Hour + 1);

  var curTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
  var firstInterval = nextRunTime.Subtract(curTime);

  //Run once on startup
  TriggerHourlyService(null);
  void action()
  {
    //Schedule the first iteration
    var t1 = Task.Delay(firstInterval);
    t1.Wait();
    TriggerHourlyService(null);

    //Schedule hourly
    _timer = new Timer(
      TriggerHourlyService,
      null,
      TimeSpan.Zero,
      interval
    );
  }

  Task.Run(action);
  return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

```cs
private void TriggerHourlyService(object state)
{
  using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
  IHourlyService hourlyService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHourlyService>();

  //ASYNC METHOD
  hourlyService.ExecuteAll();
}
```

### Update

After some notes from the comments, I've rewritten the code a bit to move away from the tutorial (it seems it was promoting some dangerous practices). However with this rewrite, my application hangs on startup. I believe it's the `await Task.Delay(...)` causing the issue, but I was under the impression this was non-blocking.

```cs
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    var nextRunTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddHours(DateTime.UtcNow.Hour + 1);

    var curTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var firstInterval = nextRunTime.Subtract(curTime);

    //Run once on startup
    await TriggerHourlyService(null);

    //First run on next hour
    await Task.Delay(firstInterval);
    await TriggerHourlyService(null);

    //Schedule hourly
    _timer = new Timer(
        async (state) => await TriggerHourlyService(state),
        null,
        TimeSpan.Zero,
        interval
    );
}
```

```cs
private async Task TriggerHourlyService(object state)
{
    using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
    IHourlyService hourlyService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHourlyService>();
    await hourlyService.ExecuteAll();
}
```

Comment: Tell me more about your service.  You have a client application connecting to a service.  Tell me how the client is communicating with the service?  You have a request and a response.  The response is <IHourlyService>

Comment: Can you please elaborate or be more direct with what you're suggesting? I'm sensing there's some sort of veiled advice that I'm not picking up on.

Comment: I don't want to disagree with you.  You said you didn't have a HttpClient.  You have a client communicating with a server.  So there is a protocol that is used to communicate.  It could be anything, but most cases these days it is HTTP.  So I need more info on the protocol.

Comment: `IHostedService` is an out-of-the-box scoped dependency in .NET Core. It runs on application startup, before the application request processing pipeline is configured, hence my confusion. Also, to clarify, when I said `HttpClient`, I meant "The `HttpClient` class" - this "Task was canceled" exception seems common with timeouts. I appreciate your help!

Comment: If that method `hourlyService.ExecuteAll();` is not blocking, then your service provider and everything created by it is disposed before anything inside that method has been run. Also, your code may run in to a deadlock by calling: `t1.Wait();`. You should rebuild that piece so you can properly `await` it.

Comment: @Santi -- `IHostedService` is injected [as transient](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.cs).

Comment: @Andy You're absolutely correct, thanks. I misread the documentation; it was stating that the *example* was activating a scoped service, rather than referring to `IHostedService` itself.

Comment: This code has many, many pitfalls. You should emulate [Microsoft's example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks). Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67114563/scheduled-task-on-net-core/67115310#67115310).

Comment: @Andy Thanks. Per Silvermind's suggestion above I had started rewriting it, which I've now shared in the question, however I'm still not understanding, evidently. Mine is the same as the Microsoft example you shared, with the one small addition of scheduling a one-time run (`Task.Delay` implements `Timer` from what I'm reading) to set it up on-the-hour. But now the application is hanging on startup.

Comment: Each hosted service is Started in the order defined, since your StartAsync method never completes, the host never starts. If you want a long running service use `BackgroundService`.

Comment: What is your communications?  Does server send a message periodically or does client send a request and then gets back a response.  Maybe you have to send something before you get something.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Good call! I just used my updated code in a BackgroundService and it seems to be working! If you'd like to post that as an answer, please do so and I'll mark it.

Comment: @Santi -- your code is nothing like Microsoft's example. Sure, you are using a timer. but that local function, then the way you call it... using Task.Run without awaiting it's results. Like I said: your code has *many* pitfalls and demonstrates a misunderstanding of basic asynchronous patterns.

Comment: @Andy Are you referring to my updated code or the original code...? I rewrote it to remove some of the "pitfalls" and be more similar to Microsoft's [Consuming a scoped service in a background task example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task). It doesn't use `Task.Run` or `.Wait()`. Everything is awaited, etc. The only thing not reflected in my update is the change from `IHostedService` to `BackgroundService`, which I've since made.

Comment: Also, could you clarify what's wrong with *"that local function"*? I literally pulled it line for line from the Microsoft example I just linked. And the "misunderstanding of basic asynchronous patterns" is exactly why I asked the question in the first place. I've learned a lot from these comments alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IHostedServce` is great if you want to run code while your host program is starting and stopping. Each service you have defined will be started and stopped in the order you define them. But if your start method never completes, the host application will never start.

If all you want is a long running loop, `BackgroundService` takes care of the start / stop lifetime for you.

```cs
public class MyService : BackgroundService{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken){
        while(!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested){
            await Task.Delay(...., stoppingToken);
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Note that your service can still block the startup of the host if you never `await` an incomplete task.