# Exception with IhostedService

Tags: c#, ihostedservice

I have been getting this exception after implementation of IHostedServices. I have no idea what is causing it. Can anyone assist?

> {"ClassName":"System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException","Message":"A task was canceled.","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":" at Core_API.Services.HourlyService.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":null,"HResult":-2146233029,"Source":"System.Private.CoreLib","WatsonBuckets":null}

Comment: This answer suggests you are running a long-running task in a context that wasn't designed for that:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275103/net-core-ihostedservice-throws-a-task-was-canceled-immediately

Comment: It mentions `HourlyService`.  Does your task take more than an hour?

Comment: That's the name of the class that implements the interface. However, the actual task takes on average, 7 seconds to run. It just needs to run every hour. Hence, that name.

Comment: @Tim I suspected this and changed the code so the task should run every minute but I still get the exception

Comment: `TaskCanceledException` is normal in many scenarios, yet sometimes not. I suggest you post more context to get a good answer.